# Create a Universal Function for a random Amount of ImageButtons located in a Random Amount of Div's Based on a Recordset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a Web Form with a Container Div that is Populated with child Div’s
Based on Data Rows from an SQL Server. The Child divs each have an ImageButton and some labels that house the partial information about the Record. I have given the ImageButton the ID of the record Set (i.e “EST-011”)   the intent is to Open a new Webform and pass the Data to the New web form
The problem is not passing information from one web form to another. I know how to do that. What I don’t know how to do is Make a Universal function for a random amount of ImageButtons Created in a Random Amount of Div’s  as of now the function is not firing Nothing happens when I click the random ImageButton
I am coding in vb.net But any solution in CSS or Jscript is welcome
'Add control to div

```
                     MyIMGBttn.Style.Add("Runat", "server")
                     MyIMGBttn.Style.Add("OnClick", "CallOpenNewWebform ()")
                     MyIMGBttn.Style.Add("Value", "Click()")
MyIMGBttn.Style.Add("Class", "ChildImgBttn")                    

                   div.Controls.Add(MyIMG)


Function Open CallOpenNewWebform()

Dim JobName As String = Me.ID' will this get the id?
        

        Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Webform9.aspx?JobName={0}", JobName technology))
       

    End Function

Webform9 on PageLoad event()' Just Shown for clarity fir fubal destination of data Key
Dim conStr As String
        conStr = connString
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
       
 Dim field1 As String = Request.QueryString("JobName") ‘Info from the div For the Query


        Try
Query Stuff Goes here.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the GridView. This would be much easier than creating controls at runtime.

Comment: To the close voter: Pretty cold to vote to close without any instruction to the poster.